# Create mesh (Geometry) from texture (black and white)

Tags: 3d, maya, 3dsmax, cinema-4d

### It is here way to make 3D mesh (geometry) from black/white texture?

Source texture is black and white map. Background is black and there is white arrow inside of texture. Now I need create 3d mesh from white color. Any kind of 3D program, 3Ds max, ...

[image]

Comment: Sure, but you should specify whether you ant a height field with 2 triangles per pixel, render time displacement or something else like traced contours extrude. Different methods have different convolutions and the way you go about depends on 3d app. But it would be much better if you actually used the original vector data instead of the pixel image.

Comment: @joojaa Yes i know this possibility, but need real mesh, not render.

Comment: renders use real meshes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it really depends on what you need the mesh to do. (a jpeg is not a good source for this data) What i would do is use the original vector image but you can vectorize it later in for example illustrator or Photoshop:

in photoshop:

1. make color a selection by copying it to a extra channel
2. and convert to work path
3. export as illustrator

In your 3d app:

1. read the vector image in and extrude
2. (optional) triangulate

[image: mesh and triangulated mesh]

**img 1:** raw n-gnon mesh and its triangulated counterpart. Done with maya 
            and photoshop (using python)

[image: a more elborate sample]

**img 2:** Same technique different picture just to show that the technique does scale

If you don't want to use a 3d app then use a vector tracing code to make a vector trace extruding that is pretty easy just duplicate the vector at a different elevation then connect vertices and fill the holes.

Code for tracing can be found at for example http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: Thank you for this full explanation. Great job!

Comment: @JinDave PS the autotrace even has a webversion so if you dont have a suitable platform to run it you can use http://www.roitsystems.com/cgi-bin/autotrace/tracer.pl to test iy

Comment: Thank you for additional link, this is good online solution. I n standalone I am using Inkspace